# MySQL: ORDER BY not working as expected. Orders some rows correctly

Tags: sql, mysql

*I don't have very much experience with MySQL so I am not sure what information I should include when asking this question.  If I am missing something relevant leave a comment.  I will promptly add it.*

I have this query:

```
SELECT 
        Log_Analysis_RecordsToSesions_dalhousie.sessionID, 
        (TIMEDIFF(
                MAX(Log_Analysis_Records_dalhousie.date), 
                MIN(Log_Analysis_Records_dalhousie.date) 
        )) as NewSessionLength
FROM 
        Log_Analysis_RecordsToSesions_dalhousie, 
        Log_Analysis_Records_dalhousie
WHERE
        Log_Analysis_RecordsToSesions_dalhousie.recordID=Log_Analysis_Records_dalhousie.recordID
GROUP BY
        sessionID;
```

Which returns this:

```
+-----------+---------------+
| sessionID | SessionLength |
+-----------+---------------+
|         1 | 00:20:31      | 
|         2 | 00:19:54      | 
|         3 | 00:04:01      | 
|         4 | 00:14:02      | 
|         5 | 00:02:16      | 
|         6 | 00:16:25      | 
|         7 | 00:00:00      | 
|         8 | 00:00:00      | 
|         9 | 00:00:00      | 
|        10 | 00:26:35      | 
|        11 | 00:11:28      | 
|        12 | 00:00:00      | 
|        13 | 00:00:00      | 
|        14 | 00:11:03      | 
  ...
|      7978 | 00:00:03      | 
|      7979 | 00:00:15      | 
|      7980 | 00:00:00      | 
|      7981 | 00:00:00      | 
+-----------+---------------+
7981 rows in set (0.92 sec)
```

When I append

```
ORDER BY
        NewSessionLength;
```

To the query it mostly sorts it but does not get it 100% correct.  *Most* of the big values get put at the end of the table and *most* of the small values get put at the beginning.  I have no idea what is causing this.

For example:

```
+-----------+------------------+
| sessionID | NewSessionLength |
+-----------+------------------+
|      4285 | 00:00:00         | 
|      1565 | 00:00:00         | 
|      7604 | 00:00:02         | 
|      4317 | 00:00:02         | 
|      1597 | 00:00:02         | 
|      7636 | 00:00:01         | 
|      4349 | 00:18:17         | // <-------------- Out of order
|      1629 | 00:00:09         | 
  ...
|      2829 | 04:28:01         | 
|       377 | 04:25:23         | // <-------------- Out of the order
|      5631 | 05:37:25         | 
|        18 | 05:05:31         | 
|      1545 | 07:01:31         | 
|      7536 | 07:09:59         | 
|      5237 | 10:07:29         | 
|       250 | 90:42:30         | 
+-----------+------------------+
7981 rows in set (0.94 sec)
```

Comment: Can you manually examine the values of sessionID = 4349 to verify the calculated length?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MySQL version 5.0.50 there was a bug ([#32202](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=32202)) where an `ORDER BY` would not work correctly when used with a `GROUP BY`. This has been fixed in more recent versions, but you may want to try the following to see if you have a "faulty" MySQL version:

```
CREATE TABLE a (id int auto_increment primary key, sorter char(5));
INSERT INTO a VALUES (1, 'z'), (2, 'x'), (3, 'a'), (4, 'z');
SELECT * FROM a GROUP BY id ORDER BY sorter;
```

If the result set you get is not sorted by the `sorter` field, then you may want to consider upgrading your database server.

If an upgrade is not possible, there is one easy workaround for the above:

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM a GROUP BY id ) b ORDER BY sorter;
```

... which in your case should be the following:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT 
            Log_Analysis_RecordsToSesions_dalhousie.sessionID, 
            (TIMEDIFF(
                    MAX(Log_Analysis_Records_dalhousie.date), 
                    MIN(Log_Analysis_Records_dalhousie.date) 
            )) as NewSessionLength
    FROM 
            Log_Analysis_RecordsToSesions_dalhousie, 
            Log_Analysis_Records_dalhousie
    WHERE
            Log_Analysis_RecordsToSesions_dalhousie.recordID = 
            Log_Analysis_Records_dalhousie.recordID
    GROUP BY
            sessionID
) dt
ORDER BY NewSessionLength;
```

Comment: This gets an error.  To fix it change it to this `... GROUP BY sessionID ) as tmp ORDER BY NewSessionLength;`